# nonnegative inverse eigenvalue problem

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, inverse-problems

Is it true that for any set of $n$ distinct **positive** real numbers $$\lambda_1 < \cdots < \lambda_n$$ there is a real symmetric matrix $A_{n \times n}$ with eigenvalues $\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n$, and $A>0$ entrywise?

If so, is there an algorithm to find the $A$ for any given input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a sketch of a proof:

First, you can put the eigenvalues on the diagonal to get a "solution" $A_0$ that doesn't quite satisfy $A > 0$. Let $F: Sym \to R^n$ be the map that produces the $n$ eigenvalues in increasing order. (Here "Sym" denotes symmetric n x n matrices).

Note that $dF/da_{ii}(A_0) = e_i$.

Now change $A_0$ to $A_1$ by adding a very small number $c$ to every off-diagonal entry. We can assume that at $A_1$, we have
$$
dF/da_{ii}(A_1) \approx e_i.
$$
In particular, for small enough $c$, these $n$ partial derivatives are linearly independent.

Now do a gradient search: the problem is that $F(A_1)$ is not the list of eigenvalues that you want, but by altering the diagonal terms, you can (by the observation about the partials) arrange to get closer to the eigenvalues that you wanted. In particular, for $c$ small enough, the alteration you need to make will be smaller than the smallest of the eigenvalues, hence all entries of the resulting matrix will still be be positive.

Comment: Great approach. Thank you very much. Is this a known technique?

Comment: I have no idea .. I just thought it up on my own. I started from the inverse/implicit function theorem, thinking about varying ALL the off diagonal entries individually, and then wondered if there wasn't a much lower-dimensional solution, and came up with the approach here. It still needs fleshing out, and I'll bet the IFT ends up playing a role, but ... we'll see, I guess.

Comment: I think where you mention the derivatives being the standard basis vectors takes care of the Jacobian and then IFT does the rest of the job.